# Wide format dataframe to long format dataframe using R

Tags: r

I am not able to convert data from long to wide format following the examples in this portal ([R how to convert from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58651973/r-how-to-convert-from-long-to-wide-format), [Converting long format to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63566323/converting-long-format-to-wide-format), [converting a long-formated dataframe to wide format tidyverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542210/converting-a-long-formated-dataframe-to-wide-format-tidyverse)). I am not sure what am I missing. I am trying to transform the long data frame to a wide format as shown  below:

[image]

```
library(tidyr)

Y  <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D")  
Z <- c("ABC","BCD","CDE","DEF","EFG","FGH","A12","B12","C12","A45","B45","C45","D45","E45","F45","G45","H45","X66","Y66","Z66")

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Y,Z))

data_wide <- spread(df, Y, Z)

Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 20 rows:
* 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
* 7, 8, 9
* 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17
* 18, 19, 20


library(tidyverse)

data_wide <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = Y, values_from = Z, values_fill = "")

Error: Can't convert <character> to <list>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is based on duplicates.  We need a unique sequence id

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
     mutate(rn = rowid(Y)) %>% 
     spread(Y, Z) %>%
     select(-rn)
```

-output

```
 A    B   C    D
1  ABC  A12 A45  X66
2  BCD  B12 B45  Y66
3  CDE  C12 C45  Z66
4  DEF <NA> D45 <NA>
5  EFG <NA> E45 <NA>
6  FGH <NA> F45 <NA>
7 <NA> <NA> G45 <NA>
8 <NA> <NA> H45 <NA>
```

---

`rowid` is from `data.table` which is a compact way to create a sequence id.  If we want to use `dplyr`, then use `row_number()` after `group_by`.  Also, `spread` is deprecated in favor of `pivot_wider`

```
df %>%
    group_by(Y) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Y, values_from = Z) %>%
    select(-rn)
```

-ouput

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  A     B     C     D    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 ABC   A12   A45   X66  
2 BCD   B12   B45   Y66  
3 CDE   C12   C45   Z66  
4 DEF   <NA>  D45   <NA> 
5 EFG   <NA>  E45   <NA> 
6 FGH   <NA>  F45   <NA> 
7 <NA>  <NA>  G45   <NA> 
8 <NA>  <NA>  H45   <NA>
```

Comment: That was so quick.

Comment: May you also please post the previous solution you posted before the above solution?

Comment: @RanonKahn I have both updates in the same post.  Is that what you meant

Comment: There was a oneliner

Comment: @RanonKahn it is the same thing :=) I just `split` into multiple lines `df %>% 
     mutate(rn = rowid(Y)) %>% 
     spread(Y, Z)`

Comment: Oh! I realize that now. Thanks a lot, if I am allowed to mention it.

Comment: three years back, I think saw your R tutorial with a lot of tips for data wrangling. If the tutorial webpages are still available, can you please provide the link?

Comment: @RanonKahn I don't remember any tutorial webpage I created though

Comment: Hi @akrun, can you please take a look at this query [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69007210/how-to-automate-plotting-a-line-plot-of-all-data-points-and-overlay-dose-respons] and suggest how to proceed further.